# Pipe hex characters to awk

Tags: bash, command-line, awk, printf

This command works as expected

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {print "\x41"}'
A
```

However when you pipe the hex character, it does not get interpreted

```
$ echo '\x41' | awk '{print}'
\x41
```

How can this be overcome?

Comment: Have you tried putting quotes around $0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, it seems it was just because I was using `echo`

```
$ printf '\x41' | awk '{print}'
A
```